# wave front solutions of the reaction-advection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I do not understand how to approach the follwoing question:

What are the wave front solutions of the reaction-advection equation
$u_t + u_x = u(1 − u)$?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by a wave front you mean a solution of the form $u(x,t)=\phi(x-c\,t)$ for some function $\phi$ (the shape of the wave front) and constant $c$ (the speed of the wave front.) Substituting into the equation we get the ordinary differential equation
$$
(1-c)\phi'=\phi(1-\phi).
$$
It can be solved by separation of variables.